# PHP echo text being output in incorrect order

Tags: php

In footer.php, I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $copyYear = 2011; 
    $curYear = date('Y'); 
    echo "&copy; " . $copyYear . (($copyYear != $curYear) ? '-' . $curYear : '') . "&nbsp;" . bloginfo('name');
?>
```

On the [front page of the website](http://www.sugargumcakes.com/), the following is output:

> Sugar Gum Cakes© 2011-2014

Note the Blog name is at the start, while in the PHP code it is at the end.

Why is this happening?  I can't see how it would be CSS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bloginfo` echoes its value on its own, use [`get_bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) within an echo, which returns its value.